# how to unset query variable

Tags: php, mysql

In order to fetch data from database (mySql) I am appending my query depending upon user requirement which he chooses from the filters I've given to him. but at a specific point if certain condition is met, so I want to unset a field (submissionDate) which was set to some variable before and set some new field to that variable. For e.g my query is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE DATE(submissionDate) between '$variablename3' and  '$variablename4'"
```

but if following condition is true:

```
if($variablename8=="Approved")
```

so I have to Append previous query and add to it

```
$query = "$query and DATE(newDate) between '$variablename3' and  '$variablename4'"
```

Note that I am appending it depending upon conditions met. So can't write all query again . Different fields will be set to different values but only if this condition is met I have to unset submissionDate and set newDate field b/w var3 and var4 and unset previous part which was:

```
DATE(submissionDate) between '$variablename3' and  '$variablename4'
```

So basically I have to neglect submissionDate effect while it will remain in the query. Is there any possible way to sort this type of problem out ?

Comment: In a nutshell: figure out what all your different clauses are **before** you produce even a single character of SQL. Set a bunch of variables in your code to `true`/`false`/values, then when everything is settled, you produce an SQL string based on those values.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make your query variable conditional.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE 1=1 AND ";

if($variablename8=="Approved")
$query .= "DATE(newDate) between '$variablename3' and  '$variablename4'";
else
$query .= "DATE(submissionDate) between '$variablename3' and  '$variablename4'";
```

Or are you looking for something else?